get distinct values of an array
I use pluck(data('thedata') , 'gender')
and get an array of all the values from 'thedata'['gender']
like male, female, male, female ...
but what I want is this
male,female
even better I want it sorted like so
female, male
I want this as an extra column in the original table and ideally grouped by brand.
This is what I have:
{ "width": 300,

  //taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309805/what-regular-expression-can-remove-duplicate-items-from-a-string
  //Perl
  //\b(\w+):(?=.*\b\1:?)
  //dotnet
    //(?<=\b\1:.*)\b(\w+):?
  //]
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "mySearchPattern", "value": "\\b(\\w+),(?=.*\\b\\1,?)"
    }
  ],
  "data":
    {"name": "thedata",
    "values": [
        {"brand": "this", "gender": "male", "Sales": 1000, "PY":    900, "Plan": 950},
        {"brand": "this", "gender": "female", "Sales":  200, "PY": 50, "Plan": 50},
        {"brand": "that", "gender": "male", "Sales":    500, "PY": 400, "Plan": 450},
        {"brand": "that", "gender": "female", "Sales":  1000, "PY": 800, "Plan": 700},
        {"brand": "something", "gender": "female", "Sales":     500, "PY": 100, "Plan": 400},
        {"brand": "something", "gender": "male", "Sales":   20, "PY": 20, "Plan": 40}
      ]
  },
  "transform":[
    {"calculate": "slice(['female', 'male'], indexof(['female', 'male'], datum['gender']), indexof(['female', 'male'], datum['gender'])+1)",
    "as": "testing"
    },
    {"calculate": "pluck(data('thedata'), 'gender')",
    "as": "allvalues"
    }
    
    ,
    {"calculate": "regexp(mySearchPattern , datum['contentofGender'])",
    "as": "myregexp"
    }
  ]  
  ,"mark":
    {
      "type": "bar"
    },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "brand", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {
      "field": "Sales", "type": "quantitative"
    }
  }
}

But I do not understand how to pass the gender to regexp to the regexp pattern.
And probably there is much more elegant way to get the distinct values from a column and get it sorted._
